# state is empty in first render

Tags: reactjs, react-native

following code give me this error : "Cannot read property 'CityName' of undefined" . but when I debug the code data state is empty only in first render and after that data has received the data from API. Is there any way to force the render to ignore the first empty state?

```js
  class profile extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data :[],
        };
       }
    
    componentWillMount() {
        axios.get(BASE_URL + 'user/' + 1)
            .then(response => this.setState({data: response.data.Result}))
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }
    
    render() {
         return (
             <View>
                <Text>{this.state.data.Profile.CityName}</Text>
             </View>
         );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first render `this.state.data` is an empty array so you should put a control for that onto your `render` method, assuming your network call is returning an array:

```
render() {
      const {data = []} = this.state;
         return (
             data.map((record, index) => <View key={index}>
                                   <Text>{record.Profile.CityName}</Text>
                                 </View>)
         );
      }
    }
```

Otherwise if your network request returns an object, then it should be something like:

```
render() {
          //You may like to show loading indicator while retrieving data:
          const {data = undefined} = this.state;
             if(data) {
                 return (
                       <View>
                         <Text>{this.state.data.Profile.CityName}</Text>
                       </View>
                 );
             }else{
                 return <View><Text>Is loading</Text></View>
             }

        }
```

Comment: excellent it's working. but still i dont understand what is doing const {data = undefined} = this.state exactly.

Comment: It is ES6's `destructuring` feature. Essentially it is the same as `const data = this.state.data` So just a shorter version of explicitly assigning the field of an object to a variable.

Answer (score 3):

You have defined `data` as empty array and then you are assigning it to object. Instead of intializing it as an empty array, intialize it as `null`.

```
class profile extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data :null,
    };
   }

componentWillMount() {
    axios.get(BASE_URL + 'user/' + 1)
        .then(response => this.setState({data: response.data.Result}))
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
}

render() {
     return (
         <View>
            {this.state.data !== null ? <Text>{this.state.data.Profile.CityName}</Text> : <Text>Please Wait</Text>}
         </View>
     );
  }
}
```

Comment: You have a typo I guess, render method should use `this.state.data` rather than `this.props.data`

Comment: sorry, but It gave me same error. @cubbuk code solved my issue.

Comment: @nrgwsth hey, if I have some Text Input and the value is based on the value of this.state.data.something, How to avoid that without error like TextInput value must be not null!

Comment: ` <TextInput
                                    value={data.username}
                                    onChangeText={(username) => { this.setState(Object.assign(data, { username: username })) }}
                                />`